# Python list comprehension does not seem to work

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to implement a list comprehension for a for loop-nested if code block. However, what seems to work using the conventional nested form does not seem to work in its list comprehension representation. From what I could see after spending a considerable amount of time is that it follows the logic as required. Please let me know if there is anything else I am skipping.

```
for x in data_list:
    if x not in encoding:
        encoding.append(x)
```

Using list comprehension

```
encoding = [x for x in data_list if x not in encoding]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
encoding = [x for x in data_list if x not in encoding]
```

What you are doing is you are *reassigning* encoding to this list comprehension `[x for x in data_list if x not in encoding]`.

So what you're doing is setting encoding to be only the elements that weren't in it in the first place.

What you should do is this:
`encoding.extend([x for x in data_list if x not in encoding])`

In this way, you're *extending the list* with the results of the list comprehension.

Here's some test code:

```
encoding = ['a','b','c','d']
encoding2 = ['a','b','c','d']

data_list = ['a','b','c','d','d','d','e','f','g']

print(encoding)
print(encoding2)

for x in data_list:
    if x not in encoding:
        encoding.append(x)

encoding2.extend([x for x in data_list if x not in encoding2])

print(encoding)
print(encoding2)
```

which prints:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Now, this is not a perfect solution, as it will still duplicate elements if they're in `data_list` more than once. The reason for this is that in the for loop example, `encoding` is checked *after each append operation* whereas the list comprehension operates only based on `encoding`'s initial state. So it will push elements into it more than once if they're in `data_list` more than once.

If you want to get around this, convert the list comprehension to a `set` first as follows:

`encoding.extend(set([x for x in data_list if x not in encoding]))`

There you have it!

Answer (score 1):

`[x for x in data_list if x not in encoding]` executes on 'one breath', so it doesn't update `encoding` on the run, resulting in empty `encoding` that leads to every item being selected.

Use `list(set(data_list))` to do what you are trying to achieve. That will convert the list to set, resulting in loss of duplicates, then convert it back to list.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
>>> list(set(a))
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a = [1, 4, 2, 5, 'g', 'd', 'g', 2, 4]
>>> list(set(a))
[1, 2, 'd', 4, 5, 'g']
```

---

If you already have data in `encoding`, you can simply add it:

```
list(set([x for x in data_list if x not in encoding]))
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not what is being asked. @codeahead wants to add any values from `data_list` that are not already in `encoding` to `encoding`. Your solution simply removes duplicates from `data_list` but ignores `encoding` entirely.

Comment: Second this—converting to a set is useful but not what is required here ultimately.

Comment: i assumed he uses `encoding` to remove the duplicates, and as you add values to `encoding` the next occurrences will be ignored. common practice for duplicate-removal amongs many

Comment: what if:  `encoding = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']` . With your solution, you would lose the duplicate `'a'`s in `encoding`.

Comment: Agree with @bunji, this is not an answer to OPs question.

Comment: @UrielEli Thank you for mentioning `[x for x in data_list if x not in encoding] executes on 'one breath'`. It has removed any doubts I had.

Answer (score 1):

Your two examples are not equivalent.  If you want to append elements from `data_list` to `encoding`  that are not already in encoding (which is what your for-loop example does), but using list-comprehension, do:

```
encoding.extend(x for x in data_list if x not in encoding)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2 `encoding`'s in your list comprehension are not the same variable. If you must have an one liner, `reduce` is more appropriate:

```
encoding = reduce(lambda l,x: x in l and l or l+[x], data_list, encoding)
```

although I don't think it's very readable.